# How to use shell to combine files and let the content have default order and no repeat lines

Tags: shell

I have 2 files, I want to combine them.
The combined content need to no repeat content and the content order is default order.

when I `uniq` them, I will use `sort`, the `sort` command make the order deranged!

so, how to use shell to combine files and let the content has default order and no repeat lines?

Comment: Ask your question with a verifiable input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear.  Do you mean that you want the order to be stable?  Do you want the inputs to be interleaved in some way?  If you just want all of the content of file 1 (in its original order) followed by all of the content of file 2 (in its original order) with duplicates removed, you can do:

```
awk '!a[$0]++' input1 input2
```

If you want the input interleaved in some way, you'll need to describe the ordering that you want. (By "default order", it sounds like you want the data sorted, but if `sort` makes the ordering "deranged", then that's clearly not what you want.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ruby to do it - sorting doesn't matter:

```
array_1 = File.read("file1").split("\n")
array_2 = File.read("file2").split("\n")
union = array_1 | array_2
```

Comment: there just can use shell